# Rust error-handling (I've got a utf8error, I want to return io::Result)

Tags: rust

I'm putting together a collection of functions for reading data from a file. All is well until I get to the read *n* bytes as a string function. Here's my current attempt:

```
pub fn read_string<R: Read>(input: &mut R, size: u32) -> io::Result<String> {
    let mut buf = vec![0u8; size as usize];
    input.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
    match str::from_utf8(buf.as_slice()) {
        Ok (v) => Ok(v),
        Err (e) => ???,
    }
}
```

I've tried a few different things for the `Err` arm of my `match` with little luck. I had hoped I could just return the `Result` from `str::from_utf8` but that didn't work. How do I take the `utf8error` in `e` and convert it into an appropriate return type for my function?

Comment: Regardless of your error handling woes, are you aware of [`std::fs::read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/fn.read_to_string.html) and [`std::io::read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/fn.read_to_string.html)?

Comment: @NieDzejkob I might be missing something, but it looks like neither of those do what I want, which is to read a fixed number of bytes as a string. I'm parsing a binary file where the strings make up a minority of the data in the file. Most of what's being read comes in 1–4 byte blocks of data.

Comment: Looking a bit deeper, those functions definitely don't do what I need. They read to the end of the file.

Comment: Ah, okay. Anyway, I thought about this for a while and I believe that the best way to resolve this is to return an error type you control, because `io::Error` doesn't expose a way for you to turn a `Utf8Error` into `io::Error`.

Comment: The downside of changing the return type is then I have to manually handle the error handling from `read_exact()` and either do that in all the other read functions or else have an inconsistent interface.

Comment: https://crates.io/crates/snafu

Comment: @Stargateur See the solution I worked out below. Something this fundamental shouldn't—and doesn't—require a crate import.

Comment: @DonHosek you are new to rust, snafu only help you to do it right it's a utils crate but it's only macro that make handle error clean and faster.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've figured it out, I needed to wrap the `Error::new` in `Err()`. I also had a type mismatch on `Ok()`. This is the working version of the function:

```
pub fn read_string<R: Read>(input: &mut R, size: u32) -> io::Result<String> {
    let mut buf = vec![0u8; size as usize];
    input.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
    match String::from_utf8(buf) {
        Ok (v) => Ok(v),
        Err (e) => Err(io::Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, e))
    }
}
```

**Edited** to incorporate NieDzejkob's suggestion for those who might want to reuse this code.

Comment: You can avoid a reallocation by using `String::from_utf8` instead.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Thanks, that improves things (plus allows me to pass the `Vec` directly instead of having to pass a slice